# Intellij IDEA: how to change the organize import feature

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I would like to know how can I avoid to make IntelliJ IDEA to automatically consolidate all the classes of a package with the `*`. For exameple let's say I have the following classes imported:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
```

now if I write later on a bit of code like the following:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

I can type <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> on either List or `ArrayList` in order to automatically import them. The problem is that once I do that, automatically IntelliJ IDEA consolidates all the imports with `java.util.*` instead of adding the single class.

I have seen the tab "organize imports" but it's not what I am looking for. What I would like to have is that in such case as the one I have above described, when typing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> I get added the single class along the others of the same package rather than having all of them consolidated in `java.util.*;`.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the Settings:
Code style -> Java -> Import Tab
in the first section (General) there is an option for *Use single class import* and at the end of the section two value fields where you can set the limit of classes in the imported package until idea starts to import `*`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in IntelliJ 14, Ultimate there is also an option under:
SETTINGS | EDITOR | CODE STYLE | JAVA | IMPORTS | to "Use fully Qualified class names".

If you check this it will NOT import your classes (as long as they're in your classpath).